# How we remove undefined getter error in node js and mongodb

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to get single key value from my level collection using node js from MongoDB
in this schema I have inserted my schema value inside the array. I think it will restrict me to access
the single value from my level collection.But I don't know how I retrieve or fetch the single key value
from my array schema or array DB in console or browser.

1). this is array schema

```
  var LevelSchema = new Schema(
   [
    {
     age: { type: Number },
     level_num: { type: Number },
     min_score: { type: Number },
     max_questions: { type: Number }
   }
 ]);
```

I know schema is write in between {} braces but my requirement is array schema and how I will fetch values or single key value
from array also.

2). this is my node js

```
   try {
      async.waterfall([
         function(callback){
            var query = { age: 5 };
            quizLevels.find(query, function(err,data) {
               if(err) return next(err);
               callback(null, data);
            });
         },
         function(data) {
            var a = data.min_score;
            console.log(data.min_score);
         }
      ]);
    }
    catch (err) { 
       console.log(err);
    }
```

i also debug my code and my debugger debug the code and show the fetched value from mongodb but when i try to go inside of this
it will shows error

```
   Runtime.getProperties failed.
   Internal error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getters' of undefined.
```

I am attaching getter error images also

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPilt.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOTfK.png)

Comment: What do you mean by `i try to go inside of this` ?

Comment: Where your waterfall code ends? and where is your final callback of waterfall?

Comment: That's not a valid Mongoose schema. What does _"my requirement is array schema"_ even mean?